# Fetch failed loading: POST Flask Restful API with 200 response

Tags: reactjs, flask, fetch

I'm trying to make a POST request to my Flask RESTful application where all GET requests responds with no problem and POST requests seems to reply correctly (tested by Restlet client and curl) but, according to the browser (chrome), they fail ("Fetch failed loading: POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/login").

Python Flask RESTful code:

```
login_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
login_parser.add_argument('email', required=True, help="Es necesario un email")
login_parser.add_argument('password', required=True, help="Es necesaria una contraseña")
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    args = login_parser.parse_args()
    try:
        user = Usuario.query.filter_by(email=args.email).first()
        if user and user.verify_password(args.password):
            token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
            if token:
                responseObject = {'status': 'success', 'message':'Successfully logged in.', 'token': token.decode()}
                return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 200
        else:
            responseObject = {'status': 'failed', 'message': 'Failed to login, usuario o contraseña incorrectos'}
            return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 400
    except Exception as e:
        responseObject = {'status': 'failed', 'message': e}
        return make_response(jsonify(responseObject)), 500
    return "Vaya uno a saber"
```

React fetch code:

```
login = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('email', this.state.username);
        formData.append('password', this.state.password);
        fetch(URL, {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(
            response => response.json
        ).then(
            json => {
                console.log(json.token);
            }
        )
    };
```

As I said, the api works from all clients but the fetch, giving me the chance to get the response code (response.status in the first "then") but denying me the chance of get the json response, witch must be:

{'status': 'success', 'message':'Successfully logged in.', 'token': THE TOKEN}

I'm really sorry about my inglish, but i'm trying to leern. Thanks you very much from now.
(My very first question in StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
  .then(
     response => response.json() // .json() is a promise function
  )
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST. One more question: still responding poorly despite the correct answer ("Fetch failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login"), should I make something about it to better performance?

Comment: No, dont think there is any better way, nothing significant at list.